# Cloning in Java object that got in attribute the same object

Tags: java, cloning

I've read this subject : http://howtodoinjava.com/2012/11/08/a-guide-to-object-cloning-in-java/.

I've done a few test and it works. Now, my problem is cloning an object A that got a list of others objects A. For example :

```
        public class Cell {
            Cell[] listOfCells;
        }
```

I tried the following code in the class **Cell** :

```
        public Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
            Cell cloned = (Cell) super.clone();

            /* Cloning the list.
             * For example, trying to clone the first cell of the list.
             */
            Cell[] clonedList = new Cell[listOfCells.length];
            clonedList[0] = (Cell) listOfCells[0].clone();
        }
```

Problem is, when calling the method on that list, each cell will call the method again etc. and then, stackoverflow.

Edit : @PaulBoddington Yes, I'm trying to do a deep copy. Yes, **listOfCells** will contains **this** (indirectly). To make it short, each cell has some neighbors (which are cells) which I've representated by a list. What I want to achieve is : cloning a cell and by modyfing this clone, it won't affect the original. For example :

```
    Cell original;
    Cell cloned = original.clone();

    cloned.die();
    cloned.listOfCells[0].die(); // the first neighbor of the clone

    cloned.showState(); // display dead
    cloned.listOfCells[0].showState; // display dead

    original.showState(); // display alive
    original.listOfCells[0].showState(); // the first neighbor of the original, must be alive
```

Comment: Posting the error stack may help;

Comment: Is it this ?

        Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError ?

Comment: If you try to do a deep copy, you will run into huge problems if `listOfCells` can contain `this` (either directly or indirectly). It's not impossible, but I'm not sure it's worth the effort. Please can you give an indication of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @PaulBoddington I've edited my first post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would avoid `clone`. `clone` is widely believed to be broken (See e.g. Joshua Bloch's Effective Java, or search this site). Instead you could write your own method.

I've written a method `deepCopy` that I think works. It uses an `IdentityHashMap` to spot when a previously encountered `Cell` is discovered to avoid computing its copy more than once.

Note that this method is still recursive, so you will encounter `StackOverflowError`s for very, very large structures anyway, but for objects that can contain themselves directly, or indirectly, there's no way to do it without using something like this.

```
// My answer assumes there is a constructor like this.
public Cell(int i) {
    listOfCells = new Cell[i];
}

public Cell deepCopy() {
    return deepCopy(this, new IdentityHashMap<Cell, Cell>());
}

private static Cell deepCopy(Cell original, Map<Cell, Cell> map) {
    if (original == null)
        return null;
    Cell copy = map.get(original);
    if (copy != null)
        return copy;
    int length = original.listOfCells.length;
    copy = new Cell(length);
    map.put(original, copy);
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        copy.listOfCells[i] = deepCopy(original.listOfCells[i], map);
    return copy;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll read this, and I will answer after understanding it.

Comment: @Eamnea I've edited my answer. It didn't make sense before because I'd used a constructor that wasn't in your question.

Comment: I've made a few tests and it seems to match what I want. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

In your clone() method replace the line

```
 clonedList[0] = (Cell) listOfCells[0].clone();
```

with

```
for (int i = 0; i < listOfCells.length; i++) {
   Cell clone = this;
   if (listOfCells[i] != this) { // avoid endless loop in case of self reference
      clone = (Cell) listOfCells[i].clone();
   }
   clonedList[i] = clone;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that is what I've intended to. That code is just an example.

Comment: sorry it was not ready, my browser tricked me. now it should be useable

Comment: Thanks for help, 'appreciate it, but an overflow still occurs.